# How to correctly type react HOC with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, high-order-component

I am new to Typescript and I cannot figure out how to correctly type HOC with it. I already spent all day to figure it out without any success. I am having very basic code snippet with `BaseComponent` and one simple `HOC`. For some reason, when creating the BaseComponent, I am getting Typescript error:

`Type '{ total: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'. Property 'total' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'`.

Any idea how to correctly set up Prop types?

**BaseComponent:**

```
interface SummaryProps {
    sum: number;
}

class Summary extends React.Component<SummaryProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.sum}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default withMyHOC(Summary);
```

**HOC:**

```
interface WithMyHOCProps {
    total: number;
}

const withMyHOC = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<any>): React.ComponentClass => {
    return class extends React.Component<WithMyHOCProps> {
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    {...this.props}
                    sum={this.props.total + 1}
                />
            );
        }
    };
};

export default withMyHOC;
```

**Initialization:**

```
import Summary from 'features/Summary.tsx';

<Summary total={5} /> // here I am getting Typescript error described above
```

Comment: Maybe you find something here https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/hoc/intro

Answer (score 0):

By passing `{...this.props}`, you are passing all the props of `withMyHOC` to the underlying component as well. This includes `total` as well, but `Summary` does not have the prop 'total'.

So oyu need to add all props to the child as well.

Comment: I removed `{...this.props}` and I am still getting the same error message. Also I tried to add `total`type to `Summary`- also getting the same error.